# Automatically build nested field, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now I'm making rails app for survey. I like to build answer fields for every questions automatically. But I can't make it.

My model

```
class Survey
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end
class Question
  hasmany :answers
end
class Answers
  belongs_to :survey
  belongs_to :question
end
```

My controller

```
class SurveyController
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    question_length = Questions.length
    question_length.times{@survey.answers.build}
  end
end
```

My view

```
= simple_form_for(@survey) do |f|
  = f.input :input_date, as: :date
  = f.simple_fields_for :answers do |ff|
    = ff.input :question_id, collection: questions.all.map{ |q| [q.title, q.id] }
    = ff.input :answer_text
```

It's working now like this, and answer fields are built for every questions. But it makes user to select question. So I want question_id built automatically for ever questions.

I've tried this controller

```
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  question_length = Questions.length
  question_array = Questions.all.map{|q| q.id}
  question_length.times{@survey.answers.build(question_id: question_array)}
end
```

But it doesn't work. If somebody knows how to make it, please advise me.

Regards

Comment: I mean, you're just doing `.build`. That doesn't actually save anything (hint: you need to call `.save` or use `.create` instead.

Comment: your answer is belonging to answer. Shouldn't it belong to question?

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks your comment. What I want is when nested answer fields are built, already question input selected by each question value.

Comment: @kiddorails Thanks your comment. I mistook it and fixed it. Thanks your pointed out.

Comment: In other way, if this model and controller, when user make survey, how can I show questions in Survey form?
My relations are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got answer.

```
class SurveyController
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    @survey.answers.build
  end
end


- @questions.each do |questions|
  = simple_form_for(@survey) do |f|
    = f.input :input_date, as: :date
    = f.simple_fields_for :answers do |ff|
      %p= questions.title
      = ff.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id
      = ff.input :answer_text
```

It's not perfect answer. But it's fine. Thanks watching my question.